# How to configure Perl Tidy not wrap the lines?

Tags: padre, perl-tidy

I am using Per Tidy plugin in Padre IDE. By default, Tidy wrap my long lines into multiple lines which I don't like. How can I tell Tidy never wrap my lines?

Comment: It would help if you could give some example input, expected output, and what you're getting.

Comment: It's not about coding. It's about format of source code in Padre IDE. When I do Tools --> Perl Tidy -> Format Active Document. Tidy will reformat the whole file I am working on to its default settings, which will wrap long lines. Is there a way to change this default settings not doing this wrap?

Comment: I don't know why "an example" is required. Configuring line length for wrapping is a rather straight-forward concept -- just hard to find in some tools that wrap other tools that mask how to actually set these underlying options.

Answer (score 2):

Testing via `perltidy` on the command-line (referring to the man page), I found that I preferred to change the default `perltidy` options to always keep newlines (line breaks) by enabling "freeze newlines" (`-fnl`), and  and disabling all whitespace modifications (`-fws`, freeze whitespace), via options: `perltidy -fws -fhl -b`

For your specific case, to ignore all line breaks, all you would needs is `perltidy -fnl -b` (the `-b` creates a backup file, and modifies in-place.)

There's also a second reasonable option of just setting the line length much longer (for example to 120 chars) than the default of 80 using: `-l=120` (or: `--maximum-line-length=120` or an even longer "really large number" is enabled by setting it to zero (`0`).

Note: as an aside, I'm testing on `bluefish` html editor, which uses either html `tidy` or `perltidy`, depending. For some reason, I had to change the rc file directly and couldn't change the setting in the GUI.

Comment: One additional thought: be sure it's `perltidy` that's actually doing the work, and not another tools like `tidy`, which is also known as "html tidy". In my case, `bluefish` uses both, depending on which menu item is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the default settings of perltidy. First find out where it is installed:

```
perl -MPerl::Tidy -e 'print $INC{"Perl/Tidy.pm"}'
```

Then edit the file where `maximum-line-length` is defined (or any other parameters you want). You might need sudo if perltidy is installed gobally. I usually use VS code to format my code and that in turn uses perltidy but I can't define paramters. So I found doing this particularly useful.